# Azure pipeline how to know commits since last deployment

Tags: azure-devops

how can I get the changes/commits which will get deployed as part of pipeline.
Earlier we used to use "Releases", which had options to see changes/commits that will get deployed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This information is available in summary of the pipeline run
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not what iam looking for. this will give for current PR. but if there were 10 PRs merged into master(since last deployment), i want to see changes in all those 10 PRs